# Missing body class

Tags: css

I'm using Themevast Boutique template #15 for Magento 2.  My installation has a large dark area across the top of the front page that the demo of the template does not have.  Firefox developer shows the top of the page in the demo as being a part of body data-container="body" class="cms-riverside1 cms-index-index page-layout-1column" aria-busy="false".  My installation does not have that css class call out.  How do I get it turned on?

The sample for the template can be seen here: http://boutique2.themevast.com/12-22/it/ 
and my installation here: 174.143.119.250

thank you for any help.  I might have a few more questions, but I hope as my skill comes up I can give back to the community in my due turn.

Comment: The best would be to contact the template creator for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this theme before, so can't say for sure, but most probably there are some theme options in:

> Admin -> Store -> Configuration -> Theme_name (probably Themevast
>   Boutique) -> Header -> check if there's an option to change header
>   types.

The `<body>` classes are dynamically loaded based on the page you're on and by certain theme options.